# getting session info after submitting a form

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, return-value

this in the code below it fails to retrieve any results, when I hardcode member_username = 'admin' it works just fine, but when I have member_username = '$kdo' it fails. Even though when I echo $kdo it prints 'admin' (without quotes)

```
<?php

                    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_username = '$kdo'");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

echo "
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Změnit kontaktní informace</legend>
                            <form method='post' action='zucet.php' class='menu_add'>
                                <p> 
                                    Email: <input type='text' name='aemail' id='aemail' value='$row[4]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Jméno: <input type='text' name='ajmeno' value='$row[8]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Příjmení: <input type='text' name='aprijmeni' value='$row[9]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Firma: <input type='text' name='afirma' value='$row[15]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Telefon: <input type='text' name='atel' value='$row[10]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Centrální tel.: <input type='text' name='actel' value='$row[11]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Město: <input type='text' name='amesto' value='$row[12]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Ulice: <input type='text' name='aulice' value='$row[13]' size='30'/><br>
                                    Čas doručení: <input type='text' name='acas' value='$row[14]' size='30'/><br>
                                    <input type='submit' name='zmenit' formaction='zucet.php' value='Změnit' /> 
                                </p>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>";

                    }

                    mysql_free_result($result);

                ?>
```

> zucet.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $con = mysql_connect("juxcore.ipagemysql.com", "*", "*") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("jux_mms");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');      

    $sql="UPDATE members SET member_email = '$_POST[aemail]' WHERE member_username = '$kdo'";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    header('Location: http://www.juxcore.com/x/vita/ucet.php');


    mysql_close($con);
```

Thanks for help, really appreciate that

Comment: where have you assigned `$kdo`?

Comment: yup, I have $kdo = $_SESSION['member_username']; which = 'admin' ATM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_username = '" . $kdo . "';");
```

Comment: are you not forgetting the session_start()?